# PrestaShop1.7.x: registering custom assets in child theme for all, not product

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

In PrestaShop (PS) 1.7, I'd like to register an additional css asset as explained in the [documentation](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/themes/getting-started/asset-management/#registering-in-themes):

> By now you probably understood that this theme.yml file became the
> heart of PrestaShop themes.
>
> To register assets, create a new assets key at the top level of your
> theme.yml, and register your files according to your needs. Page
> identifiers are based on the php_self property of each controller
> (example)
>
> For example, if you want to add an external library on each page and a
> custom library on the Product page:
>
> ```
> assets:
>   css:
>     product:
>       - id: product-extra-style
>         path: assets/css/product.css
>         media: all
>         priority: 100
> ```

But, instead of doing so for a *product*, I want to do it for *all*:

```
 assets:
   use_parent_assets: true
   css:
     all:
       - id: my-custom-colors.css
         path: assets/css/my-custom-colors.css
         priority: 51
```

This appears not to be working. It is also extremely similar to [this question](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/829940-creating-a-child-theme-using-ps-1732/) on the PS forum, which is as of today unanswered.

Can this be done at all, or am I originally at fault by not understanding the docs?